# SSRS report with .NET Core, The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, reporting-services

I'm trying to generate an SSRS report from .NET Core application and I'm following this [tutorial](https://docubear.com/how-to-generate-a-ssrs-report-from-a-net-core-application/)
But I'm getting the following exception

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.

When I remove the credentials and use `BasicHttpSecurityMode.None` with `HttpClientCredentialType.None` everything is working fine but I need to add credentials to the service

I know there are many answers to this error but I've tried almost all of them but nothing is working for me

Here is what I've tried:

I tried to add `ProxyCredentialType` to be `Ntlm` but I got the same error

```cs
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Ntlm;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760; //10MB limit
var rsExec = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(SSRSReportExecutionUrl));
var clientCredentials = new NetworkCredential(SSRSUsername, SSRSPassword, ".");
if (rsExec.ClientCredentials != null)
            {
                rsExec.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
                rsExec.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = clientCredentials;
            }
```

Also I tried to replace `HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm` with `HttpClientCredentialType.Windows` but I got this error

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'

Some answers suggest modifying `web.config` file or using Microsoft Service Configuration Editor to edit it but I don't found this file or this editor in my case, I think these exist in .NET framework, not .NET core but I'm not sure

Any idea what should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running to the exact same error with the code in the OP

Comment: @ShameWare I figured out the solution a while ago, but I forgot to post it. I've added an answer; I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me, I removed `binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType` line and added `binding.UseDefaultWebProxy` to be true;

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 0;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5242880;
binding.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;

binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;

var rsExec = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(SSRSReportExecutionUrl));
rsExec.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
rsExec.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Answer (score 1):

For those that are encountering this issue "out of the blue", it's more than likely that the users password has expired.

Answer (score 1):

My Experience with this error was similar to Adam's. It seems this error message is quite misleading... My case was a .netCore8 web app (deployed in Azure App Services) calling a WCF service with NTLM auth.

The problem for me was that the username/password configuration properties werent bieng set correctly and were defaulting to junk values. So I would have expected an invalid username/password type message, but instead wasted a day thinking there was something wrong with my bindings / WCF setup.

hopefully this saves someone else one day!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, most of the cases on the web are deployed with IIS and verified using Windows Authentication. If you're using IIS, only change the Windows Authentication enabled and try following the steps in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36289/8-steps-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-WCF-Ba).

If it doesn't work out, try using Kerberos and registering an SPN before using it.